# User Profile Synchronization Service error

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service, profile-sync

I am having a strange error with our user profile service application .When i tried to start the user profile synchronization service it will take some time saying starting and then it will stop when i had checked the event log it is giving me the following error `

```
The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ProfileSynchronizationSetupJob (ID 7ea785aa-844c-43f3-87be-2d64003a538d) threw an exception. More information is included below.

The object ProfileSynchronizationSetupJob Name=ProfileSynchronizationSetupJob has been deleted by another user since it was last fetched.`
```

**Update 1.**
I tried deleting the user profile and recreating again from the scratch but for the new applications also it is giving the same error ..Somebody please help..

Comment: any recent SP updates installed? did you run the config wizard to finish the update? This is usually what gets me with UPS.

Comment: yes david  one of the recent update has made some change and  i actually ended up running the farm configuration wizard again ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To isolate the problem during setting up of User Profiles sync, it is very common that you may not get to the actual error straightaway. The right way to get the actual error message is to use the Synchronization service manager (MIIS Client).

Path to MIIS Client can be found here:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Synchronization
>   Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe

For e.g. you might get the following error in MIIS Client

> Error: Replication access was denied. error code: 8453

Which means your UPS sync account doesn't have permissions to replicate Directory Changes. So you have to grant more permissions to your UPS sync account in AD before running UPS sync.

Here is the architecture overview of UPS sync. I would also recommend you to take a look at [Harbar's guide for configuring UPSA](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx)

[image]

Some Pre-Reqs before you provision UPS:

**Permissons:**

- Farm account is local admin on SP server [remember to remove after!]
- Farm account can log on locally
- Farm account is administrator for UPA

**Most common issues:**

- Farm account is not a administrator on the machine, which results in 1) Timerjob will fail. 2)You can remove local admin privileges after configuration is complete
- Failing to do an IISRESET after starting the User Profile. Please do and IISReset and try again
- User Profile Sync Account needs permissions in AD, which means 1)Replicate Directory changes. 2) Write Permissions (if you write back)

**Best practice**

- Use a Dedicated Service Account for UPS Sync

Hope it helps

Comment: @Anil don't forget to also mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You must ensure all the points taken care of before you start the User Profile Sync Service as mentioned here - [Rational Guide to implement user profile synchronization service](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx) and [Stuck on Starting UPSC problems](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx). With time, these articles has somewhat become a defacto reference for User Profile related issues and almost majority of the issues have root causes identified in the missing steps , as discussed in these articles.

However, looking at the corelation log you shared I may have some quick pointers for you regarding the same

- Check that the FIM (Forefront Identity Manager) services in the windows services MMC are configured with the correct credentials.
- Check the replication rights(Replicating Directory Changes) of the service account in AD before running UPSC.
- Validate the service account status in the AD like there no password expiry or similar settings that might be blocking the account. There is a good chance the health of the service account might be in a incorrect state which may be causing SharePoint to intiate the process of enabling synchronization however it fails ahead with the account provided to sync with the AD

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your farm account is in local admin group when you set up the UPSS.